# virtual machine does it come prebundled with jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, virtual-machine

Excuse my ignorance about vm related stuff, as I am rather new to using vm. Currently I am working on a project that at the least to say has me making some key decisions.. one if which is to develop around tech that comes bundled with vm. Me not knowing much outside of knowing the company I am doing this project for wants to add as little as possible that doesn't come prebundled with a vm. Based on a project that is almost entirely based on java where I am doing the front end to work with it UI wise wants to stick with the notion of not adding more to the over all then nessisary so I'm just curious..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that you actually mean the "Java Virtual Machine" (JVM). No, that's just part of the JRE/JDK which in turn is usually *not* shipped along with any JSP/Servlet container. You have to install it separately.

A JSP/Servlet webapplication is usually delivered in flavor of a WAR or EAR file. The enduser (or its serveradmin) has usually to take care about the installation of the JRE/JDK and the servletcontainer themself.

Comment: Yes, JVM would be the one. The project was developed solely on JAVA originally with the intention of a CLI use. Now the project is going in a different direction and they would like to have a UI for non CLI savvy people to use as well as to just consolidate some of the functionality. They are bundling there product up within the JVM and giving it to there clients that way. So with that the UI portion is going to be a web app rendition of the CLI stuff. I know they don't want to have to bundle more than needed so its easier to get it out of the box and running quickly for clients

Comment: There exist embedded servletcontainers. Jetty for example. It can be started and deployed programmatically using a simple Java class with a `main()` and so on. I think this is what you're *actually* looking for. Then the enduser only has to take care that the JRE is preinstalled.

Comment: That could work. I mean from my understanding I know a tech from the company I am working with will be going out to do the initial installs and configurations. But same notion applies that the company wants as little configuration and installation as needed for ease of use. But its also for the sake of keeping movable parts to a minimum going in hand with the bit of only wanting as little as possible to be added to a standard JVM download/install. Thanks for your help.